# KerasTuner: Custom Metrics (e.g., F1 Score, AUC) in Objective with RandomSearch Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using KerasTuner for hyperparameter tuning of a Keras neural network. I would like to use common metrics such as F1 score, AUC, and ROC as part of the tuning objective. However, when I specify these metrics in the kt.Objective during RandomSearch, I encounter issues with KerasTuner not finding these metrics in the logs during training.

Here is an example of how I define my objective:

```
tuner = kt.RandomSearch(
    MyHyperModel(),
    objective=kt.Objective("val_f1", direction="max"),
    max_trials=100,
    overwrite=True,
    directory="my_dir",
    project_name="tune_hypermodel",
)
```

But I get:

```
RuntimeError: Number of consecutive failures exceeded the limit of 3.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/base_tuner.py", line 273, in _try_run_and_update_trial
    self._run_and_update_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/base_tuner.py", line 264, in _run_and_update_trial
    tuner_utils.convert_to_metrics_dict(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/tuner_utils.py", line 132, in convert_to_metrics_dict
    [convert_to_metrics_dict(elem, objective) for elem in results]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/tuner_utils.py", line 132, in <listcomp>
    [convert_to_metrics_dict(elem, objective) for elem in results]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/tuner_utils.py", line 145, in convert_to_metrics_dict
    best_value, _ = _get_best_value_and_best_epoch_from_history(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/tuner_utils.py", line 116, in _get_best_value_and_best_epoch_from_history
    objective_value = objective.get_value(metrics)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/objective.py", line 59, in get_value
    return logs[self.name]
KeyError: 'val_f1'
```

Are the actual metrics available on the Keras documentation? I have searched and I can't seem to find them. The only snippet of code that has worked for me is using the accuracy metric like this:

```
import keras_tuner as kt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
from kerastuner.tuners import RandomSearch


class MyHyperModel(kt.HyperModel):
    def build(self, hp):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(layers.Flatten())
        model.add(
            layers.Dense(
                units=hp.Int("units", min_value=24, max_value=128, step=10),
                activation="relu",
            )
        )
        model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))  
        model.compile(
            optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=hp.Float('learning_rate', 5e-5, 5e-1, step=0.001)),#,Adam(learning_rate=hp.Float('learning_rate', 5e-5, 5e-1, sampling='log')),
            loss='binary_crossentropy',
            metrics=['accuracy']
        )
        return model

    def fit(self, hp, model, *args, **kwargs):
        return model.fit(
            *args,
            batch_size=hp.Choice("batch_size", [16, 32,52]),
            epochs=hp.Int('epochs', min_value=5, max_value=25, step=5),
            **kwargs,
        )


tuner = kt.RandomSearch(
    MyHyperModel(),
    objective="val_accuracy",
    max_trials=100,
    overwrite=True,
    directory="my_dir",
    project_name="tune_hypermodel",
)

tuner.search(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping('val_loss', patience=3)])
```

Is it possible that Keras only supports accuracy as the default metric, and we'll have to define any other metric ourselves? How can I define objective metrics for AUC and F1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide  [Getting started with KerasTuner](https://keras.io/guides/keras_tuner/getting_started/#specify-the-tuning-objective) from the official documentation answers your question:

> In all previous examples, we all just used validation accuracy ("val_accuracy") as the tuning objective to select the best model. Actually, you can use any metric as the objective. The most commonly used metric is "val_loss", which is the validation loss.

There are two type of metrics you can use:

- Built-in metrics. You can find the list of built in metrics on the official documentation: [Keras Metrics](https://keras.io/api/metrics/)
- Custom Metrics: those metrics, you need to define them yourself by subclassing the `Metrics` class.

In both case, when defining your `Objective`, you need to use the `name` attribute of the Metric object you want to use as an objective. The guide states it quite clearly:

> Identify the objective name string. The name string of the objective
> is always in the format of f"val_{metric_name_string}". For example,
> the objective name string of mean squared error evaluated on the
> validation data should be "val_mean_absolute_error".

Note that the metric used as an objective should be compiled with the model:

> Compile the model with the the built-in metric. For example, you want
> to use MeanAbsoluteError(). You need to compile the model with
> metrics=[MeanAbsoluteError()]. You may also use its name string
> instead: metrics=["mean_absolute_error"]. The name string of the
> metric is always the snake case of the class name.

---

So in your case, given that you would like to use a F1 metric as an objective, you need to:

- Compile your model `MyHyperModel` with the metric. You can use the [one defined by TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/F1Score) if you are using TensorFlow as a backend (or using Keras 2.15), or alternatively, define the metric yourself (See the guide: [Creating custom metrics](https://keras.io/api/metrics/#creating-custom-metrics))
- Use the right name when defining your objective. If you use the one defined in TensorFlow, you would use `val_f1_score` as a name (if you wish to use the f1 score computed on the validation data as your objective).

Repeat those steps with every metric you wish to use.

Comment: THANK YOU LESCUREL I DO APPRACITE YOUR HELP thank you for your time and effort would you so kind as to show me a code to complie the F1 metric? because its not builtin

Comment: Have a look at how it's defined in TensorFlow: [f_score_metrics.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.15.0/keras/metrics/f_score_metrics.py)

Comment: OMG thank you so much Lescurel thanks a lot indeed you are a TRUE legend this is amazing!!!!!!!!! I'm will be happily awarding you with the bounty thank s a lot my friend from the bototm of my heart!!!! THIS IS GREAT!